# what is identity column in sql server ? and what are the types of identity in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am new in sql server. Can any body explain me what is identity column in SQL server & is it there any types of identity column.

Comment: check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three type of Indentity in sql server . Please refer this link .

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/different-between-scope-identity-ident-current-and-identit/